# Jquery Mobile - URLs in popup window on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently facing an issue that has been driving me mad for the past 4 hours.

I am using Jquery Mobile on my page to create a modal/popup window. This popup window has 5 containers that contain href links. When the page is opened on a mobile browser, and the popup window loaded, the containers fall vertically and a user must scroll down and select the necessary link to continue.

On every browser except Mobile safari I can scroll down to any of the links and click on them and the link loads. However on Mobile Safari, only the first two links are clickable. When you click any of the others it jumps to the top of the modal window & the URL is underlined. This is similar to what you see if you were tabbing through links on any page with text links.

The code for all the containers is identical except for the href URLs, but i have checked them to death & they all work in mobile chrome/firefox.

Would really appreciate any guidance/tips to debug and work out why mobile safari is being so strange.

EDIT: Adding in code:

The modal window contains links that are defined by some javascript (i.e. the user changes some drop downs and this changes the URLs in the modal window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.button_change').change(function(e) {

var an = $(this).val();
var d1 = $("#id_1").find(":selected").attr("name");
var d2 = $("#id_2").find(":selected").attr("value");
var d3 = $("#id_3").find(":selected").attr("value");
var d5 = $("#id_4").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d4 = $("#id_5").find(":selected").attr("value");


var option1_url = ("https://localhost:8888/register/" + d4 + d1 + "/plan1" + "/?utm_term=" + d3  + "&utm_medium=" + d5);
var option2_url = ("https://localhost:8888/register/" + d4 + d1 + "/plan2" +"/?utm_term=" + d3 + "&utm_medium=" + d5);
var option3_url = ("hhttps://localhost:8888/register/" + d4 + d1 + "/plan3" +"/?utm_term=" + d3  + "&utm_medium=" + d5);
var option4_url = ("https://localhost:8888/register/" + d4 + d1 + "/plan4" +"/?utm_term=" + d3 + "&utm_medium=" + d5);
var popup_modal =("#myPopupDialog");

$('.button-plans1 a').attr('href',option1_url);
$('.button-plans2 a').attr('href',option2url);
$('.button-plans3 a').attr('href',option3_url);
$('.button-plans4 a').attr('href',option4_url);


});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary button-plans-popup clickable">
      <a class="button-color" href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade">NEXT</a>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Modal Window</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">



<div class="selection-types">


  <div class="module option1" style='display:none;' id='option1'>
     <div class="inner">     
        <div class="button-plans1">
      <a href="/signup/option1/" class="button">Register for Plan 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <div class="module option2" style='display:none;' id='option2'>

    <div class="inner">


        <div class="button-plans2">
      <a href="/signup/option2/" class="button">Register for Plan 2</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="module option3" style='display:none;' id='option3'>

    <div class="inner">

        <div class="button-plans3">
      <a href="/signup/option3/" class="button">Register for Plan 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="module option4" style='display:none;' id='option4'>

    <div class="inner">


        <div class="button-plans4">
      <a href="/signup/option4/" class="button">Register for Plan 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: I see a number of mistakes in the code. Could you please find them and fix them? Maybe they have something to do with the problem. (Hint: they are with variable names). Also, is it possible that some of the URL references do not exist? I think some more self-debugging is needed.

Comment: Thanks bcdan. I will clear up the code, but it turns out it's not just links. It is clicking anywhere in the lower half of dialog window :(